# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException in JBoss Wildfly and JPA Injection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cdi, inject

I try to make a simple Inject of my entityManager from a JPAUtil.class to my DAO. when I make a instance it works but when a try to make the @Inject I get a null pointer exception. Maybe is something easy but I do not get it.

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>model.Client</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prueba1" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="kevinsantiago" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

class DAO

```
package dao;

import model.Client;
import model.JPAutil;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import javax.persistence.Query;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Diese Class ist die verbindung
 * mit die Data base Erzeugen
 */

public class ClientDAO {
    //HIER WORKS WOTHOUT PROBLEM
    //EntityManager entity = JPAutil.getEntityManeger();
    //HIER DOES NOT WORK
    @Inject
    @Named("Pruebe")
    private EntityManager entity;

    public void create(Client client) {
        entity.getTransaction().begin();
        entity.persist(client);
        entity.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    public void update(Client client) {
        entity.getTransaction().begin();
        entity.merge(client);
        entity.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    public List<Client> findall() {
        Query q = entity.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c");
        List<Client> listaC = q.getResultList();
        return listaC;
    }

    public Client findbyId(int idc) {
        Query q = entity.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE id=" + idc);
        Client C  = (Client) q.getSingleResult();
        return C;
    }

    public void remove(int id) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c = entity.find(Client.class, id);
        entity.getTransaction().begin();
        entity.remove(c);
        entity.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

JPA

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


/**
 * Hier ist erzeugt die entitty manager,
 * um in die Dao zu nutzen
 */
public class JPAutil{
    private static final String PUName = "jpa";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    private static EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    @Named("Pruebe")
    public static EntityManager getEntityManeger() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PUName);
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManegerFactory() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PUName);
        }
        return factory;
    }

    public static void shutDown() {
        if (factory != null) {
            factory.close();
        }
    }


}
```

and now a just want to copy the Error

```
Context Path:/JSFJPA_HelloWorld_war_exploded
Servlet Path:/index.xhtml
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deployment.JSFJPA_HelloWorld_war_exploded.war//dao.ClientDAO.findall(ClientDAO.java:43)
    at deployment.JSFJPA_HelloWorld_war_exploded.war//controller.ClientBean.AllClients(ClientBean.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:245)
    at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:338)
    at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2//com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:202)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:479)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:468)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:540)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1153)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1644)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP04//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.Final//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    ... 49 more
```

If you have advice or comments it will be a pleasure read it, because every feedback is welcome. I have just started to learn this technology.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want use CDI you can avoid static factory:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa")
private EntityManager em;

@Produces
public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return em;
}
```

Put a beans.xml file in your WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" >

</beans>
```

Here the doc:

> When you deploy a Java EE application, CDI looks for beans inside bean archives. A bean archive is any module that contains beans that the CDI runtime can manage and inject. There are two kinds of bean archives: explicit bean archives and implicit bean archives.
>
> An explicit bean archive is an archive that contains a beans.xml deployment descriptor, which can be an empty file, contain no version number, or contain the version number 1.1 with the bean-discovery-mode attribute set to all.
>
> An implicit bean archive is an archive that contains some beans annotated with a scope type, contains no beans.xml deployment descriptor, or contains a beans.xml deployment descriptor with the bean-discovery-mode attribute set to annotated.
>
> In an implicit archive, CDI can only manage and inject beans annotated with a scope type.

Now you can use

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;
```

**EDIT**

> For a web application, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, if present, must be in the WEB-INF directory. For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, if present, must be in the META-INF directory.

Comment: i have try to make the changes that you have told me. but I have the same Problem. I had the Beam.xml and with the new changes does not work yet =S.

Comment: did you add the beans.xml?

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast answer you are really kind I going to add the git repository and the answer is. Yes I have the beams.xml

Comment: there ist the repository will be great if you can check it just to see if a had all in order thank every comment and advice are welcome. https://github.com/SantiRey/JFSJPA_HelloWorld

Comment: There is a main class ... are you deploying the application in a container, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, there is one main class. that is just a test for JPA. this class do not have any real use in the Project and any Relation with the Project too and I am using Wildfly as Server. that is what you mean with Container ?. again thanks for your time.

Comment: Your app is packaged as a JAR, not as a WAR, then beans.xml must be in META-INF directory. Edited answer.

Comment: @KevinSantiagoRey: Code should be in the question, not in a remote repository!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Comments, it was really helpful. I going to read about Containers. I think that is my Problem. after that write again. Thank again.